# How can I query to find out if my MacOS/X app is in app-nap mode?

Tags: c++, macos

I've got a C++ app (Qt-based) running on MacOS (10.10 and newer), and I'd like it to modify its behavior slightly when it is running under MacOS's [app-nap mode](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/10/os-x-10-9/13/).  (In particular, there are some periodic network queries it does in order to update status indicators in its GUI, but if the application is napping I'd prefer that it stop doing them until after it has woken up from its nap).

If I had a function like this:

```
 bool IsThisProcessNapping();  // returns true iff we're in app-nap mode
```

... I think I could implement the behavior I want, but I don't know of any such function.  Does it exist under some other name?

(Note that I don't want to just disable app-nap, since I want my program to be energy-efficient if possible)

Comment: I have no earthly idea why anyone would downvote this question. I don't know how you can do it programatically. I know there are log entries for nap events in the system log, but that would seem a pretty ghetto solution. Genuinely curious myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a specific answer to your question (I don't think the API you talk about actually exists).

You could start by reading [Energy Efficiency Guide for Mac Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/AppNap.html), especially the section "Enhancing App Nap":

> By default, your app becomes eligible for App Nap if it’s not actively
>   engaged with the user and hasn’t updated a visible window for some
>   length of time. However, your app knows the most about the importance
>   of its activity, and shouldn’t rely on App Nap to put it into an idle
>   state. The most effective way to enhance App Nap is for your app to
>   listen for notifications that it’s no longer in active use and to
>   suspend energy-intensive work as quickly as possible

Given the scenario you describe (pausing network requests to update status indicators), check out [Notify Your App When Visibility Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/WorkWhenVisible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013929-CH18-SW1).

It has examples of the application delegate methods `applicationDidChangeOcclusionState:` and `windowDidChangeOcclusionState:`. When your app or the relevant window is occluded, you could pause your network activity, and resume it when the occlusion state goes back to visible.

The guide mentioned above also links to similar documentation for checking the active state of your app.

If your app is not visible, and not active, it's a candidate for App Nap. At that point, what difference does it make in your case if the app is actually napping yet? If your aim is to be energy efficient, pause your network activity once the app is not visible - since no-one can see your status indicator anyway!

Comment: Yes, I did look into that, and I think tracking my app's occlusion-state would be helpful.  The problem is, AFAICT the only way to get my app's occlusion-state is via callback methods called on the NSApplicationDelegate object, which Qt doesn't give me access to (it's declared only in their private header files).  I'm not terribly fluent in Objective C++; is there a way to install a second NSApplicationDelegate, or to forward a callback on the original NSApplicationDelegate over to an object that I have control of?

Comment: Well, I don't know much about Qt, but can you use `NSNotificationCenter`? I just did a test and it works to add observer to `NSApplicationDidChangeOcclusionStateNotification` and `NSWindowDidChangeOcclusionStateNotification` respectively, using for example `addObserverForName:object:queue:block`

Comment: I was able to get NSNotificationCenter to work, but it turns out to be overkill for my needs -- in the end all I needed was a function that returned a boolean, so I went with:  `bool is_application_occluded() {if ([NSApp occlusionState] & NSApplicationOcclusionStateVisible) return false; else return true;}`

Comment: Oh nice one! Yes, I forgot you were just asking for method to call rather than a notification. Glad you got it figured out!